# Is it possible to install 32bit Solaris10 on a 64bit SPARC system?

Tags: compatibility, solaris

I have a system with a 64bit SPARC processor.  Does the 32bit installation for Solaris 10 support such a system?

Comment: Which processor?

Comment: UltraSPARC-IIIi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if the 32-bit Solaris 10 [has a 64-bit kernel](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/64_bit_booting.html#Q1).

Comment: so a 64 bit kernel is necessary, but you can have a 32 bit runtime?

Comment: Correct. This is how it's done on other operating systems such as Linux.

Answer (score 3):

There is no 32-bit installation for Solaris 10 on SPARC.   There is a single unified installation that provides a 64-bit kernel, and the ability to run both 32-bit & 64-bit userspace programs.   Solaris 10 dropped support for pre-64-bit SPARC CPU's, since SPARCs have been 64-bit since 1995.